# Keras more Conv3D with more than 3 channels

Tags: python, keras

I have a question regarding keras Conv3D layer. My input are 3D volumes with 4 channels (image plus segmentation masks).

Now Iam wondering how the conv3D layer should be set up to work properly? When I write :

```
Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
```

or

```
Conv3D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
```

and print out the filter shape it says:

(3, 3, 3, 4, 64)

When I write:

```
Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 4), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
```

though, the filter shape is:

(3, 3, 4, 4, 64)

As far as I have understood, the kernel depth should be the same as the image depth, or number of channels.

Now Iam wondering what the correct way is and why the filter shape has 5 dimensions. I would have expected 4 (heigh, width, depth, number of kernels)

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

M

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectations are correct regarding what the "layer output" should be, but I think you might be confusing the shape of the internal layer "kernel" with what comes out of the processing from that layer.  Below, I've provided an example code with some printouts of relevant quantities.  I believe that if you look at the output of the myModel.summary(), you'll see what you are expecting.  Please note that Keras using "None" for the sample dimension-it is determined from the actual input data.  I hope this helps.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

output_units=7

input_data = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(16, 16, 16, 4))
c3d = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(output_units, (3,3,3), padding='same', name='c3d') (input_data)
x = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(c3d)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
myModel =  tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_data, outputs=x)

myModel.summary()

x_train = np.random.random((20,16,16,16,4))
y_train = np.random.random((20,1))

myModel.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mse')
myModel.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=1)

print(x_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)

mmy = myModel.get_layer(name='c3d')
print(mmy.kernel.shape)  # This shouldn't be confused with the layer output from the myModel.summary() above.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As far as I understand you have a volume with 4 channels in your example and you define the filter size as (3,3,3). I think thats were I get confused. Why not (3,3,4) to cover all 4 channels? Or is convolution performed on each channel seperately?

Comment: I believe each channel is processed with a separate set of weights which are then combined with the weights of all the other channels and the final result shows up in a given output unit.  This process is essentially repeated for each output unit.  So in the case I provided, each of the 7 output units will have contributions derived this way.  All four channels are thus automatically taken into account (even though you are only specifying the spatial dimensions in the "kernel", which basically slides around within the volume)  I hope this helps.